# Wso2 Scim Api cant fetch groups

Tags: ldap, wso2, openldap, scim, wso2-identity-server

I have connected Wso2 ti an external LDAP. Through the admin panel i can see the users and roles that are fetched from LDAP.

However when requesting groups using Scim Api like

```
https://10.4.0.17:9443/wso2/scim/Groups
```

only groups that belong to the internal `PRIMARY` UserStore are fetched.The problem is that i use the external LDAP UserStore as my main UserStore.So i should not get any groups from that UserStore.

How do i configure Scim to fetch from the external LDAP instead of the internal `PRIMARY` ?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48643727/questions-about-wso2is-version-5-4-and-scim2-groups). At the moment at least for Readonly LDAP, groups are not added to the internal DB. You can add it manually to the DB.This is of course not a solution and I filled an issue [on github](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/2309). If you are still interested in a fix, you can upvote the issue.

Comment: In my case, we are using ReadAndWrite Ldap user store. Is it affected as well?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. We switched to keycloak some time ago.